# Select data week by week by setting Wednesday as the first day of the week

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I would like to create a stored procedure that I can select data week by week. How can this be done? Here is my situation, the employees fill up the timesheet every day and payment is made weekly every Wednesday morning. So Wednesday is the first day of the week. I want to display the data in a gridview. In my gridview, each page in the gridview should represent each week the employees work. For example, if there are 7 records and today is Wednesday 02 Oct, 2013 and each record for each day in the last 7 days, so

1. the oldest record was entered on 25 September, 2013,
2. the second oldest record was entered on 26 September, 2013
3. the third oldest record was entered on 27 Sept, 2013 ...
4. the 7th oldest record was entered on 1 October, 2013

In my gridview, I want to display on page 1, the record from 25 Sept - 1 October only. It's kind of grouping the gridview page by week with Wednesday as the first day of the week. I hope I can get my point across.

Thank you for your help.

**Copied from comment**

Here is how I can determine the start and end date of a week based on worked_date:

```
SELECT *
, dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',worked_date) / 7, '20000105') AS WeekStart
, dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',worked_date) / 7, '20000105')+6 AS WeekEnd 
FROM Timesheet
```

Comment: sql server function date(dw, yourdate) will give you the day of the week where weeks start on Sunday.  Add or subtract to it to get a value where Wednesday is 0 and Tuesday is 6.  That will get you started.

Comment: Hello Dan, I can get day of the week just fine. How can I group data week by week. From 25 Sept to 1 Oct, it is one week. I can specify in my query where worked_date between 25 Sept And 1 Oct. But that will select only one week data. Is there a way I can select all data and group week by week. Thanks

Comment: Here is how I can determine the start and end date of a week based on worked_date: SELECT *, 
  dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',worked_date) / 7, '20000105') AS WeekStart,
   dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',worked_date) / 7, '20000105')+6 AS WeekEnd
  FROM Timesheet

Comment: Hello everyone, I tried to figure out the logic of this and here is what I can come up with but not sure how to write the query. So here is the logic: 
Today is 02 October 2013
First I get how many weeks between min(worked_date) and max(worked_date) As integer and get this reflected in my gridview. If it is page 2 on the gridview, 
I want to select only the records where date_worked is from 25 September to 01 October. If it is page 3 on the gridview, I want to select 18 September to 24 September and so on. Thanks.

Comment: Anybody could help me please? Much appreciated.

Comment: Anybody could help? I am trying to put the logic together.First i can count the number of weeks and then select only the week that is requested. Something similar to this query: HAVING DATEDIFF(WEEK, min(worked_date), max(worked_date)) = @PAGENUMBER

Comment: Here is another piece of information: If there are three weeks, the user select 2, it means the user wants only the second week. then it would be 3-(3-2)=2. If there there 4 weeks, the user select 2, it means the user wants only the second week. then it would be 4-(4-2)=2. if there are 4 weeks, the user select 3, then 4-(4-3)=3. Could you help me put this login together please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant way but this works for me to get the top rank number:

```
 WITH CTE AS (

            SELECT employee_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, ''20130925'', worked_date )/7 DESC) AS weekRank
            FROM Timesheet
            )

            SELECT TOP (1) weekRank  
            FROM CTE
            WHERE employee_id=@employee_id  
            ORDER BY weekRank DESC
```

This is how I can create weekRank column and pass a parameter dynamically:

```
WITH rank_cte AS (
SELECT timesheet_id,employee_id, date_worked, 
    dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',date_worked) / 7, '20000105')   AS WeekStart, 
    dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20000105',date_worked) / 7, '20000105')+6 AS WeekEnd,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY 1 + DATEDIFF(DAY, '20130925', worked_date )/7 DESC) AS  weekRank
FROM Timesheet

)

 SELECT timesheet_id, worked_date, WeekStart, WeekEnd, weekRank 
 FROM rank_cte rc 
 WHERE  employee_id=@employee_id 
 AND weekRank=@weekRank
 ORDER BY worked_date  DESC
```

Thanks